# Aligning certain list of strings by its content

Tags: string, python-3.x, indexing, alignment

I have a large text file i need to parse into an excel. The raw format similar to this which shows a shopping list:

```
Name: Peter
Eggs
Chicken
Fish
Rice
Total:4

Name: Jane
Eggs
Spam
Total:2

Name: David
Rice
Bread
Fish
Total:3
```

I am able to parse it into a list which could be exported into excel using openpyxl:

```
[('',),('Name', 'Peter', 'Eggs', 'Chicken', 'Fish', 'Rice', 'Total', '4', '', ''),('Name', 'Jane', 'Eggs', 'Spam', 'Total', '2', '', ''),('Name', 'David', 'Rice', 'Bread', 'Fish', 'Total', '3')]
```

There can be only a maximum number of 6 items to buy but I still need each of the items to be separated.

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
    text = f.read().replace('\r\n',',')

text = text.replace(':',',')
text = text.replace('Name',':Name')
text = ','.join(text.split('\n'))
text = text.strip()
text = text.replace(', ',',')

text3 = [tuple(x.split(',')) for x in text.split(':')]
```

This is the output in .xlsx but i would prefer to have the "total" aligned, is there a possible way to do it? Since I could only have a fixed number of items (6 max), is there a way that I can make all the "total" into column I or index 8 in "text3" of my code?

This is an output sample, https://i.stack.imgur.com/r22B2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of going about this. I'd start by processing the source file line by line because this will conveniently give you the beginning and end of a record. However, you've chosen to do this differently and now want to normalise the tuples you create.

You can do this by removing all empty strings from the tuples:
`t = [i for i in t if i != '']`
You then locate the position of "Total"
`idx = t.index("Total")`
And pad the list with empty strings
`t.insert(idx, '')`
You need to do this in a loop to make sure the length is constant.